# How can I create a unit test for a function that passes in an Event Object as a dependency?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I have a function on an input field that adds a percent sign to the value from the user input. The function looks like the following:

```
addPercentSign: function (oEvent, control) {
  var inputVal = oEvent.getParameters().value;
  var inputNumber = parseFloat(inputVal);

  if (inputNumber) {
    if (inputNumber < 50 || inputNumber > 100) {
      return null;
    } else {
      var finalVal = inputNumber.toFixed(1);
      var finalOutput = finalVal + "%";

      control.learningCurve.setValue(finalOutput);
    };
  }
}
```

Since this function relies on an Event object, how can I 'mock' the parameters (oEvent object) (using Sinon.js or mocks) to create a unit test for this function? The rule of thumb for unit tests are to isolate the unit (addPercentSign function) as much as possible without any dependencies.

Since the oEvent object is how we retrieve the user input, I'm not sure what the strategy is to write this specific test? Would I simply create an object in my unit test that looks identical to an event object?

```
QUnit.test("Check for Percent Sign", function (assert) {

        var testOEvent = {value: '25'}

        assert.ok(formatter.addPercentSign(testOEvent) == 25, "Test");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You call this function with an object that mocks all the interfaces of the event that your function is uses.

For example:

```
var testOEvent = {
   getParameters:function(){
      return {value:"1.0"}
   }
}
```